# Import CSV formatting escape sequences

Tags: excel

I'm generated a CSV file that I want to import into Excel. Are there escape sequences that can be imbedded in the CSV file that will format a cell automatically? I'm trying to get a number 1234.00 or 5678.20 to format as money (1234.00 or 5678.20) rather than the 1234 or 5678.2 that Excel wants to do. I've found some for font formatting (bold, italic, etc) but nothing for data type.

Comment: Please tell what have you tried, and also, showing few columns of your data as example would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not aware of escape sequences that can be embedded in a csv file which will cause excel to change the font formatting. Can you give some examples?  Or a link?